# How to handle with pop up in selenium webdriver

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I am doing first time automation (Have very less knowledge about selenium) and I am not able to handle with popup in webdriver.

This is my website link http://www.burbank.com.au/ in this I want to click on "VICTORIA" link text.

Please explain me in detail.

Comment: There are plenty of resources are there to handle the popups, google it!

Answer (score 0):

Its not a popup, its a part of the home page.

```
driver.findElement(By.id("victoriapopbtn")).click();
```